# Is it possible to make compass compile only modified partials?

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

We use compass/sass in a large-scale project, with hundreds of partial scss files. When running 'compass compile' it takes more than a minute to compile the output css file.

1. Does compass use caching on a partial level?
2. Is it possible to force compass to compile only the modified files?
3. Is it possible to run compass in a 'verbose' mode so I can understand how the cache is being used?

Answer (score 0):

Compass will compile only modified files if you use `compass watch [path/to/project]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use compass watch to compile only modified files but if you have any partials ,changes in them won't be compiled unless you add import path as for example `add_import_path "stylesheets/sass"` into your config.rb