# Managing & Scaling SASS projects for multiple .NET Projects

Tags: css, .net, deployment, tfs, sass

**Current Scenario**

Currently I have a Front-End folder in TFS independent of the .NET Projects. This FE project has a SASS project is structured very similar to as mentioned here

http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

Difference is that we have multiple of these to cater for multi-regional sites... So structure looks something like

[image]

**Problem**

When we create a new .NET project we manually copy this "SASS Projects" and move it **IN to .NET Project** manually and make changes there... so suddenly we have 2 copies of the SASS projects in 2 different locations. If there are 3 .NET projects then that makes it 3 copies. These projects are deployed individually there is no "common" server for the CSS

So this is a pain in the backside to maintain the code

**What we trying to achieve...**

Maintain just one single SASS codebase under SASS Projects. Check in all the changes to single "SASS Projects/" folder in TFS. However ensure that .NET projects could be developed/deployed using these files in TFS with the CSS inside the .NET Projects?
So every time a FE dev check in "SASS Project" can these changes be automatically distributed to .NET projects?

Is this the best practice?
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into creating extensions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949004/sass-or-less-packaging

Answer (score 0):

You can run sass server with the demon that will constantly monitor sources for the change  with compass ([Is it possible to make compass compile only modified partials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603903/is-it-possible-to-make-compass-compile-only-modified-partials/23605850#23605850))